# SFMCSdk (Android) crash when inboxMessageManager trying to connect already-closed SQLiteDatabase (get messages)

Tags: android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, inbox

We have fresh android setup (target 34) with Jetpack Compose and in our Marketing Cloud-related repository instance `inboxMessageManager` is successfully initialised (code below) but when restart activity happens for example with changing dark/light theme and trying to reference instance's property `messages`, next crash happens:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException attempt to re-open an
> already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase

Related code:

```
private lateinit var inboxMessageManager: InboxMessageManager

    init {
        SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
            sdk.mp {
                inboxMessageManager = it.inboxMessageManager
            }
        }
    }

    fun getMessages(): List<InboxMessage> = inboxMessageManager.messages // Crash reason
```

So would it be possible to InboxMessageManager provide for example safety check to SQLLiteDatabase? Or some example for best practise when fetching inbox messages with modern android way? Thank you.

Comment: Open a support case.

Comment: Where are you initializing the SDK?

Comment: In MainActivity. SDK initialization should be fine as push notifications, in-app and inbox messages arrive successfully. SDK version 8.1.3

Comment: You _must_ initialize the SDK in your application's Application#onCreate().

Comment: @BillMote That got everything working nicely (not sure why initialization had been set to MainActivity in first place) - thanks very much of your time Bill, it's highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You *must* initialize the SDK in your application's Application#onCreate(). This seems like it's being initialized with the activity and your property won't be valid between launches of the activity.